# tf.keras two losses, with intermediate layers as input to of one of them error:Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, tf.keras

I want to have two losses in my tensorflow keras model and one of them takes an intermediate layer as input. 
This code works when I use keras but when it comes to tensorflow.keras I face the following error.

```
def loss_VAE(input_shape, z_mean, z_var, weight_L2=0.1, weight_KL=0.1):

  def loss_VAE_(y_true, y_pred):
      c, H, W, D = input_shape
      n = c * H * W * D

      loss_L2 = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=(1, 2, 3, 4)) # original axis value is (1,2,3,4).

      loss_KL = (1 / n) * K.sum(
          K.exp(z_var) + K.square(z_mean) - 1. - z_var,
          axis=-1
      )

      return weight_L2 * loss_L2 + weight_KL * loss_KL

  return loss_VAE_

def loss_gt(e=1e-8):

  def loss_gt_(y_true, y_pred):
      intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=[-3,-2,-1])
      dn = K.sum(K.square(y_true) + K.square(y_pred), axis=[-3,-2,-1]) + e

      return - K.mean(2 * intersection / dn, axis=[0,1])

  return loss_gt_


model.compile(
    adam(lr=1e-4),
    [loss_gt(dice_e), loss_VAE(input_shape, z_mean, z_var, weight_L2=weight_L2, weight_KL=weight_KL)],
    # metrics=[dice_coefficient]
)
```

Error:

```
_SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'Dec_VAE_VDraw_Var/Identity:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Dec_VAE_VDraw_Mean/Identity:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=float32>]
```

Is it bug? 
please find the complete code in this [NOTEBOOK](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1stvEzOTG8K8V9FqLpfSFD2emOJsUjipo).

and [THIS](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LjP2GnpcqcGWdg3wNlFI7WZCi59L_-dK) is the link to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `K.mean` to `tf.reduce_mean` and accordingly all the keras backend functions to tensorflow functions solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If running under the eager mode,tensorflow op will check if the inputs are of type "tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor" and Keras ops are implemented as DAGs. So the inputs to the eager mode will be of *tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor* and this throws the error

You can change the input type to EagerTensor by explicitly telling tensorflow to run in the eager mode for Keras.

*tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)*

Adding this statement should solve your issue. Although note that there will be significant performance hits since you are running now in eager mode and recommended only for debugging, profiling etc.

Comment: this solved the first error but causes another error:TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.

Comment: Nothing. I edited the question added a link to the data in case you need it

Comment: Try to train your code like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced). this will work. and make tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(False)

Comment: I have already tried the custom loop but there I face a problem while applying gradients.